# OCR that outputs probability data

Tags: ocr

I would like to convert printed books I own into audio by scanning them with OCR and then running the text through a TTS engine. These titles are not available as ebooks.

Since OCR can make small errors especially when converting images containing old typefaces, I would like to find an OCR engine that can tag each region of text with metadata describing the engine's perceived likelihood of a correct match, or an array of other possibilities. For example, see Google Voice's voicemail transcription, which highlights each word in shades of gray indicating the speech-to-text engine's probability ranking.

Do you know of any packages that offer this?

Comment: I notice that you have asked 14 questions and have received answers to most of them but have accepted one. Could you go through your older questions and accept the answers that solved your problem? I doubt that none of them did.