# Distro for low-RAM with most recent package versions

Tags: distribution-choice, distributions

Are there any distros that are designed to make a wide range of very recent (unstable) packages available on low-RAM systems?

Comment: How low is "low-RAM"?  If you mean 100 MB+, you can use any distro -- they will all offer the same opportunities to use or not use ram; the question in this case is more about how to configure the system.  Eg. no one thinks of ubuntu as "light" but an LTS server will run in <32 MB of RAM.  So to be clear: **They are all the same.  No one distro uses any more or less RAM than any other.**

Comment: Seriously, stop asking so many questions without accepting any answers. I ask you [again](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92674/ocr-that-outputs-probability-data#comment140032_92674), please go through your old questions and accept those that solved your issue or answered your query. Otherwise all these questions remain open which is bad for the site.

Comment: Maybe you could also re-factor your older question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92524/low-ram-linux-distro-specifically-for-serving-static-sites

Answer (score 1):

This kind of question gets asked a lot and it hinges on a fundamental confusion.

The amount of RAM you use is determined by the software you are running, not the distro you installed.  "But", you say, "Doesn't the distro I installed determine the software I am running?"

Yes, but in the sense that (for example), ubuntu uses a different init daemon than fedora.  I'm not sure which one of those uses the most RAM, but if you have a look at `top -p 1` (the pid of the init daemon is always 1) you'll see why no one would care one way or the other.  You won't find a distro that manages to save on RAM by not using an init daemon.

Pretty much every general purpose distro will provide you with the **exact same** opportunities to run mem heavy or mem lite software and that software will be the **exact same** on ALL distros.  The distros *do not write the software*.  They just configure and package it.

Distros like Arch or Gentoo, which permit for much more customization during install, in a sense make it easier to install minimal systems which do not occupy much *disk space*.  However, it might be observed that since:

1. The custom install process with those distros is quite a bit more complex and time consuming than it is with distros that use a less flexible installer;
2. The process of *removing* components is relatively easy on all of them;

for most people, taking a fat (e.g.) Ubuntu install and paring it down to the point where it is equivalent to a minimal Arch install will probably take *less time* than just installing a minimal Arch.

This is not to knock Arch or Gentoo.  This is just to say that using them "because they are lighter" somehow is a misconception.  That's not why they exist and that's not a justification for choosing them over something else.

Further, **running *the same software stack* on Ubuntu or Debian or CentOS or Arch or Whatever will result in *the same memory usage*.**

---

If you want to minimize RAM usage, there are two scenarios to consider:

1. I don't want/need a GUI.
2. I do want/need a GUI.

If the scenario is #1, then you're set.  A full fledged linux system *without X* will fit in ~20-25 MB of RAM, whether it's ubuntu or fedora or arch or whatever.

Of course, if you are running services, those are additional -- but they will be the same addition regardless of distro.

If the scenario is #2, then you want to use a lightweight DE (desktop environment), or a stand-alone WM (window manager).  There are configurations with the latter which can run in <100 MB.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want unstable on a server, at least on a production server. If you want recent and less heavy, try Debian unstable or Arch.

Comment: I think the "heaviness" you refer to here is disk usage and not ram usage -- there is nothing special about debian or arch in that respect.  Also, debian is usually not considered the most up-to-date distro around.

Comment: @goldilocks he said `unstable`.